# How to use Parameter List of integers for Oracle with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dapper, sqlparameter

I am trying to re-write some code to use Dapper so I can easily use parameters. I am trying to execute an UPDATE statement on an Oracle database. A list of `IDs` to UPDATE is passed in as `List<int>` as parameter. I want to update a field for each of the `IDs` passed in. The following is what I have:

```
OracleConnection connection = ... // set earlier

public int IncreaseProcessCount(List<int> ids)
{
    var rowsAffected = connection.Execute(@"UPDATE TABLE SET PROCESSED_COUNT = PROCESSED_COUNT + 1 WHERE ID IN @ids", new { ids });
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Before using Dapper, the execution statement was working just fine. Now I am getting following error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression.

My current solution is based on below posts:

[Dapper query with list of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291589/dapper-query-with-list-of-parameters) and 
[Performing Inserts and Updates with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957774/performing-inserts-and-updates-with-dapper)

Comment: Try casting your list to an array, as in `new { ids.ToArray() }`

Comment: @RobertHarvey no such luck. :( Thanks, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT \* FROM X WHERE id IN (...) with Dapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388093/select-from-x-where-id-in-with-dapper-orm)

Comment: Your setting of the OracleConnection earlier is a code smell. Likely you're not following the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern correctly. It wouldn't cause the issue you're seeing now, but it's probably something you need to fix. And when working with Oracle, it uses `:colons` instead of `:ampersands` to do parameters, as shown [here](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) (warning, I contributed the examples for that page).

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure if this is Oracle specific issue as I never worked with Oracle + Dapper combination. But I strongly suspect the way you are passing parameter is a problem. The exception "missing expression" is saying the same thing.

Refer modification of your code below:

```
public int IncreaseProcessCount(int[] ids)
{
    var rowsAffected = connection.Execute(@"UPDATE TABLE SET PROCESSED_COUNT = PROCESSED_COUNT + 1 WHERE ID IN :ids", new { ids });
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

There are following differences:

1. **Use of "`:ids`" instead of "`@ids`"**. I strongly suspect this is an issue because Oracle expects `:` instead of `@` for parameters.
2. Use of `int[]` instead of `List<int>`. This should not be an issue because Dapper [supports](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#list-support) `IEnumerable` for parameter list; so `List` should be OK. You have already tried this (as you mentioned in comments) without success.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8388093/5779732) question for Dapper with `IN` clause using Parameter List. Here is [another](http://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-list) resource.

## Edit (for comments):

The core of the problem was use of "`:ids`" which was correctly included in my answer. I just corrected syntax error in the code above.

Also, I generally use `DynamicParameters`. Actually, it was not an issue in this case, so I removed that part which was present in first version of my answer. Anyway, following is the code with `DynamicParameters` which should work equally.

```
public int IncreaseProcessCount(int[] ids)
{
    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add(":ids", ids);

    var rowsAffected = connection.Execute(@"UPDATE TABLE SET PROCESSED_COUNT = PROCESSED_COUNT + 1 WHERE ID IN :ids", param);
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: @jollyroger23 The reason you need to wrap the array in an anonymous object is that you *could* have other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Based off Amit's answer, below is what I finally got to work. I had to wrap the collection being passed in with an anonymous object.

```
connection.Execute("UPDATE TABLE SET PROCESSED_COUNT = PROCESSED_COUNT+ 1 WHERE ID IN :ids",
                    new { ids });
```